# Pattern match on value of Either inside a for comprehension?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, for-comprehension, either

I have a for comprehension like this:

```
for {
      (value1: String, value2: String, value3: String) <- getConfigs(args)
      // more stuff using those values
}
```

`getConfigs` returns an `Either[Throwable, (Seq[String], String, String)]` and when I try to compile I get this error:

```
value withFilter is not a member of Either[Throwable,(Seq[String], String, String)]
```

How can I use this method (that returns an `Either`) in the for comprehension?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
for {
   tuple <- getConfigs()
} println(tuple)
```

Joking aside, I think that is an interesting question but it is misnamed a bit.
The problem (see above) is not that for comprehensions are not possible but that pattern matching inside the for comprehension is not possible within `Either`.

There is [documentation how for comprehensions are translated](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) but they don't cover each case. This one is not covered there, as far as I can see. So I looked it up in my instance of "Programming in Scala" -- Second Edition (because that is the one I have by my side on dead trees).

### Section 23.4 - Translation of for-expressions

There is a subchapter "Translating patterns in generators", which is what is the problem here, as described above. It lists two cases:

#### Case One: Tuples

Is exactly our case:

```
for ((x1, …, xn) <- expr1) yield expr2
```

should translate to `expr1.map { case (x1, …, xn)  => expr2)`.
Which is exactly what IntelliJ does, when you select the code and do an "Desugar for comprehension" action. Yay!
… but that makes it even weirder in my eyes, because the desugared code actually *runs* without problems.

So this case is the one which is (imho) matching the case, but is *not* what is happening. At least not what we observed. Hm?!

#### Case two: Arbitrary patterns

```
for (pat <- expr1) yield expr2
```

translates to

```
expr1 withFilter {
  case pat => true
  case _ => false
} map {
  case pat => expr2
}
```

where there is now an `withFilter` method!
This case totally explains the error message and why pattern matching in an `Either` is not possible.

The chapter ultimately refers to [the scala language specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/) (to an older one though) which is where I stop now.

So I a sorry I can't totally answer that question, but hopefully I could hint enough what is the root of the problem here.

#### Intuition

So why is `Either` problematic and doesn't propose an `withFilter` method, where `Try` and `Option` do?
Because `filter` removes elements from the "container" and probably "all", so we need something that is representing an "empty container".

That is easy for `Option`, where this is obviously `None`. Also easy for e.g. `List`. Not so easy for `Try`, because there are multiple `Failure`, each one can hold a specific exception. However there are multiple failures taking this place:

- `NoSuchElementException` and
- `UnsupportedOperationException`

and which is why `Try[X]` runs, but an `Either[Throwable, X]` does not.
It's almost the same thing, but not entirely. `Try` knows that `Left` are `Throwable` and the library authors can take advantage out of it.

However on an `Either` (which is now right biased) the "empty" case is the `Left` case; which is generic. So the user determines which type it is, so the library authors couldn't pick generic instances for each possible left.

I think this is why `Either` doesn't provide an `withFilter` out-of-the-box and why your expression fails.

Btw. the

```
expr1.map { case (x1, …, xn)  => expr2) }
```

case works, because it throws an `MatchError` on the calling stack and panics out of the problem which… in itself might be a greater problem.

Oh and for the ones that are brave enough: I didn't use the "Monad" word up until now, because Scala doesn't have a datastructure for it, but for-comprehensions work just without it. But maybe a reference won't hurt: [Additive Monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Additive_monads) have this "zero" value, which is exactly what `Either` misses here and what I tried to give some meaning in the "intuition" part.

Comment: The SLS actually has a chapter on [for-comps](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) where it says where `withFilter` arise from. Note, however, the bit about "irrefutable". Actual scalac always inserts `withFilter`, then checks refutability and removes it after typechecking - and on stuff like Either, typecheck has failed by then due to lack of `withFilter`.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks for the insight. I didn't go into that much detail, because the SLS is not that easy to read but it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want your loop to run only if the value is a Right. If it is a Left, it should not run. This can be achieved really easy:

```
for {
  (value1, value2, value3) <- getConfigs(args).right.toOption
  // more stuff using those values
}
```

**Sidenote:** I don't know whats your exact use case, but `scala.util.Try` is better suited for cases where you either have a result or a failure (an exception).
Just write `Try { /*some code that may throw an exception*/ }` and you'll either have `Success(/*the result*/)` or a `Failure(/*the caught exception*/)`.
If your `getConfigs` method returns a `Try` instead of `Either`, then your above could would work without any changes.

Comment: Adding right gives me this: 

```value withFilter is not a member of scala.util.Either.RightProjection[Throwable,AppConfig]
[error]       params: AppConfig  <- getConfigs(args).right```

Comment: Try to use `Try` instead (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/EwLc9Ok9QsqAn4om2oCuHw) or additionally convert the right to an option (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/u0AiA9JuSSOybqK4bYgDVg)

Answer (score 2):

I think the part you may find surprising is that the Scala compiler emits this error because you deconstruct the tuple in place. This is surprisingly forces the compiler to check for `withFilter` method because it looks to the compilers like an implicit check for the type of the value inside the container and checks on values are implemented using `withFilter`. If you write your code as

```
  for {
    tmp <- getConfigs(args)
    (value1: Seq[String], value2: String, value3: String) = tmp
    // more stuff using those values
  }
```

it should compile without errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Oleg's [better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) compiler plugin:

`build.sbt`:

```
addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.2.4")
```

And then:

```
object Test {
  def getConfigs: Either[Throwable, (String, String, String)] = Right(("a", "b", "c"))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val res = for {
      (fst, snd, third) <- getConfigs
    } yield fst

    res.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
a
```

This works because the plugin removes the unnecessary `withFilter` and `unchecked` while desugaring and uses a `.map` call. Thus, we get:

```
val res: Either[Throwable, String] = 
  getConfigs
    .map[String](((x$1: (String, String, String)) => x$1 match {
      case (_1: String, _2: String, _3: String)
    (String, String, String)((fst @ _), (snd @ _), (third @ _)) => fst
}));
```